# how to create hbm files from java files?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Is there any eclipse plugin available to create hibernate hbm file from java file??
I want to create hbm from java files and hence the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html).

Comment: In the Tools package there should be an ANT-Task called java2hbm.